# ASP.NET MVC get all users that contains one role

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I would like to list all users that contains one specific role.

Here what I'm trying to do:

```
foreach (var user in db.Users.Where(x => x.Roles.Select(y => y.Role).Contains("Admin")).ToList())
{}
```

But this is getting the error:

```
Error   2   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityRole>' does not contain a definition for 'Contains' and the best extension method overload 'System.Linq.Queryable.Contains<TSource>(System.Linq.IQueryable<TSource>, TSource)' has some invalid arguments
```

how can I make this working?

**FIX**

```
foreach (var user in db.Users.Where(x => x.Roles.Select(y => y.Role.Name == "Admin").FirstOrDefault()).ToList())
```

Comment: have you tried splitting up the query into multiple parts? EF isn't translating the `Contains` correctly, and the fix is usually either to switch the condition around or materialize the results

Comment: Have you tried:
db.Users.Where(x => x.Roles.Where(s => s.Role.Contains("Admin")).ToList();

Comment: Can't you start your query from Roles.Singe(s=>s.name="Admin) and traverse from there to your users

Comment: If you've solved your problem, you should write it in as an answer and mark it accepted.